# Which version of Rolle's theorem is correct?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

**#According to my textbook**:

Rolle's theorem states that if a function $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a, b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$ such that $f(a) = f(b)$, then $f′(x) = 0$ for some $x$ with **$a ≤ x ≤ b$**.

**#According to Wikipedia**:

If a real-valued function $f$ is continuous on a proper closed interval $[a, b]$, differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$, and $f(a) = f(b)$, then there exists at least one $c$ in the **open interval** (a, b) such that
$f'(c)=0$.

So one definition says that $c$ should belong in closed interval $[a,b]$ but the other says that $c$ should be in open interval $(a,b)$.

Which definition is correct ? Why?

Comment: Neither are definitions, both are correct, but the Wikipedia statement is stronger.

Comment: @copper.hat What do you mean by stronger? Can you give an example where the textbook definition becomes invalid but the Wikipedia definition is valid ?

Comment: The second is more precise.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam I get it that the second is more precise. But why ? Can you provide an example where the textbook definition is invalid but the Wikipedia definition remains valid ?

Comment: @TheStackExchange: As said, they are noth correct, so I cannot give an example. The Wiki statement makes a (marginally) stronger statement about where you can find the $c$ (that is, in $(a,b)$, not just $[a,b]$).

Comment: This is not a definition so saying "give an example where the textbook definition is invalid" is not really meaningful. Both statements of the theorem are true. If the one from Wikipedia holds (which it does), then clearly the one from your textbook also holds. This is why we say the Wikipedia statement is stronger: because it implies the textbook statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are *theorems*, not definitions, and both of them are correct.  Notice that if Wikipedia is correct, then your textbook is automatically correct as well: if there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$, then there also exists $x\in [a,b]$ such that $f'(x)=0$, since you can take $x=c$ (since $(a,b)$ is a subset of $[a,b]$).  On the other hand, you can't (in any obvious way) deduce Wikipedia's statement from your textbook's, so Wikipedia's statement is *stronger*: it tells you more information.  So you could say Wikipedia's statement is more *useful* or more *powerful*, and is "correct" in that you might as well use it instead of your textbook's version.

As for which one is "correct" in the sense of being the "standard" statement of Rolle's theorem, I would say the Wikipedia version is probably more standard.  But mathematical theorems quite often do not have universally accepted "standard" versions and instead have several different versions that are closely related but may be slightly different and all tend to be referred to with the same name.  It's not like there's some committee of mathematicians who gets together and declares "this is the statement we will call Rolle's theorem"; everyone just refers to theorems independently and so there ends up being some minor variation.

Comment: Nicely written. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

It would most likely be wikipedia, but for small things like this it doesnt really matter. If you are tested, just follow your textbook.

Wikipedia logic:

$$f(x) = 4-x^2$$
f is continuous on $[-2,2]$

f is differential on $(-2,2)$

$f'(c) = 0 \to  x = 0$

and $ x \in (-2,2)/[-2,2] $

Thus both are valid, but as you can see, the $0$ is more valid inside the interval (wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

In both the theorams 2 things are common
1.) Function is continuous on $\left[a,b\right]$
2.) function is differentiable on $\left(a,b\right)$$\Longrightarrow$may be or may not be differentiable at x=a and x=b.
Case 1. 
$\Longrightarrow$function is differentiable at x=a and x=b

Both theorams are correct
Case 2. 
$\Longrightarrow$function is not differentiable at x=a and x=b

textbook theoram becomes improper.Where wikipidea theoram is still
correct